# Capistrano 3 pulling command line arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rake, capistrano

I'm in the process of upgrading from Capistrano 2 to Capistrano 3. In Cap 2 I was using the following to take a command line argument as the branch name (otherwise default to `master`)

```
set :branch, fetch(:branch, "master")
```

If I called `cap deploy` it would deploy the master branch. But it also let me do something like this:

```
cap deploy -S branch=foo
```

Which would deploy the `foo` branch.

Now, in Capistrano 3, if I try to run the above I get an error: `invalid option: -S`.

What's the proper way to pass an argument via the command line now?

Comment: I found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capistrano/-MWCt9faKz4) but no resolution that I could tell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rake tasks (which cap is using) are supporting arguments.

```
namespace :test do
  desc "Test task"
  task :test, :arg1 do |t, args|
    arg1 = args[:arg1]
    puts arg1
  end
end
```

cap -T outputs:

> cap yiic:test[arg1]                # Test task

Example of invocation:

> cap production yiic:test[test1]

Also, here is a helpful [post](http://viget.com/extend/protip-passing-parameters-to-your-rake-tasks)

P.S.: you should use env vars for "global" settings. Like common values for multiple tasks.

Answer (score 40):

What I ended up doing was setting an `ENV` variable.

So now I can call

```
cap production deploy branch=mybranch
```

And it will deploy `mybranch`. If I run a simple `cap production deploy` it will deploy the default branch (`master` if you don't set one, but I've changed mine below to `default` to demonstrate)

This is the code I put in my `deploy.rb` file:

```
set :branch, "default"
if ENV['branch']
        set :branch, ENV['branch']
end
```

Comment: To make it DRY, `set :branch, ENV['branch'] || 'default'`

Comment: Env vars are for global settings (like login, or changing some deaults). You should't use it for task args

Comment: You still can use `fetch` to get the env var set in that way.

Comment: **UPD:** no, fetch(:branch) is glitchy, since it returns `master` by default. Better use `branch=asd` and `ENV["asd"]`

Answer (score 1):

To give an updated and working solution for Capistrano 3 (as it took me a while to find and too many tests to make it works).

My files are like:

```
config/
    deploy/
        staging.rb
        production.rb
    deploy.rb
...
Capfile
```

In `staging.rb` I have:

```
server 'staging', roles: %w(db)

set :branch,    ENV.fetch('REVISION', 'master')
set :use_sudo,  false
set :user,      'toto'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www'
```

(In `server 'staging'`, `staging` is a SSH connexion, defined in my `.ssh/config`)

Then, to deploy a specific revision, I just need to call:

```
cap staging deploy REVISION=3b2d9ab
```

Where `3b2d9ab` is the Git commit hash (short or long version).