# Can I get capistrano to remember answers from an ask?

Tags: environment-variables, capistrano

Is it possible to configure Capistrano so it will remember previous choices?

for example, when asking for a branch name:

```
ask :branch, 'master'
```

I would like it to remember the last branch name rather than using the default `master`.

If that is not possible, would it be possible to use an environment variable in place of `master`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to remember answers, but setting from environment variables is pretty simple.

```
ask :branch, ENV.fetch('BRANCH', 'master')
```

That also allows you to specify the arguments on the command line eg:

```
cap prd deploy BRANCH=special
```

Thanks go to [this answer to a slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322778/1062129).