# How to pass command line parameters to capistrano

Tags: ruby, command-line, capistrano

I am using Capistrano v2.9.0.

I run this command:

```
cap deploy:tryout -S testvar=thing
```

and my deploy.rb contains this:

```
namespace :deploy do
    task :tryout do
        if defined? testvar
            puts "param: #{testvar}\n"
        else
            puts "no branch!\n"
        end
    end
end
```

The output is "no branch!". How do I pass values from the command line? I tried looking into the code, and I can see options.rb where it adds the passed parameter to options[:pre_vars], but that seems to be an instance variable, and I can't figure out how to access it from my deploy script.

Comment: Is the `-S` a typo? it should be `-s` (lowercase)

Comment: No, according to the cap docs, lowercase is --set, uppercase is --set-before. I've tried it with both of them, anyway.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216841/passing-parameters-to-capistrano -- Also, testing variable existence looks like this: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Configuration-Variables-Exists -- I believe vars set on the command line are tested the same way. Try putting your var in the else and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The options can be accessed via @parent.variables hash, so if the command line string is `testvar=thing`, then `@parent.variables[:testvar]` has the value `string`.

This seems really ugly and hacky, but it works.

Edit:
Turns out it is also available locally via `variables[:testvar]`